# Echo server chat application having issues connecting

Tags: python, sockets, networking, network-programming, echo

I'm a novice when it comes to networking, but for my distributed systems project I'm attempting to create a simple application that allows any computer on the same network with python to send messages to a server. I cannot get my computer and laptop to connect successfully, and I get a timeout error on the client side:

Here is my server code:

```
import socket
import select

HEADER_LENGTH = 10
IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 1234

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))
server_socket.listen()

sockets_list = [server_socket]

clients = {}

def receive_message(client_socket):
    try:
        message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)

        if not len(message_header):
            return False

        message_length = int(message_header.decode("utf-8").strip())
        return {"header": message_header, "data" : client_socket.recv(message_length)}

    except:
        return False


while True:
    read_sockets,  _, exception_sockets = select.select(sockets_list, [], sockets_list)

    for notified_socket in read_sockets:
        if notified_socket == server_socket:
            client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()

            user = receive_message(client_socket)
            if user is False:
                continue

            sockets_list.append(client_socket)

            clients[client_socket] = user

            print(f"Accepted new connection from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]} username:{user['data'].decode('utf-8')}")

        else:
            message = receive_message(notified_socket)

            if message is False:
                print(f"Closed connection from {clients[notified_socket]['data'].decode('utf-8')}")
                sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)
                del clients[notified_socket]
                continue

            user = clients[notified_socket]

            print(f"Received message from {user['data'].decode('utf-8')}: {message['data'].decode('utf-8')}")

            for client_socket in clients:
                if client_socket != notified_socket:
                    client_socket.send(user['header'] + user['data'] + message['header'] + message['data'])

    for notified_socket in exception_sockets:
        sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)
        del clients[notified_socket]
```

Here is my client code

```
import socket
import select
import errno
import sys

HEADER_LENGTH = 10

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 1234

my_username = input("Username: ")
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((IP, PORT))
client_socket.setblocking(False)

username = my_username.encode("utf-8")
username_header = f"{len(username):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode("utf-8")
client_socket.send(username_header + username)

while True:
    message = input(f"{my_username} > ")

    if message:
        message = message.encode("utf-8")
        message_header = f"{len(message):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode("utf-8")
        client_socket.send(message_header + message)

    try:
        while True:
            #receive things
            username_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            if not len(username_header):
                print("connection closed by the server")
                sys.exit()

            username_length = int(username_header.decode("utf-8").strip())
            username = client_socket.recv(username_length).decode("utf-8")

            message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            message_length = int(message_header.decode("utf-8").strip())
            message = client_socket.recv(message_length).decode("utf-8")

            print(f"{username} > {message}")

    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN and e.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            print('Reading error', str(e))
            sys.exit()
        continue

    except Exception as e:
        print('General error', str(e))
        sys.exit()
```

On the same machine, it works as expected since I'm using the hostname for both the server and client, but obviously, it will not work on separate devices.

How may I change this code so that I can get my laptop to act as a client, and my computer to act as a server? I only need to connect to devices on the same network. Thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself, I just had to set the 'IP' in client to that of the server local IP, and lastly run both in IDLE so I would get the prompt to bypass the firewall, as I was running cmd previously and was not getting the option to bypass.